# qt crashes on opening

Tags: c++, qt

[image]I am trying to get qt set up on my computer to make a gui for a c++ program. I installed it with no issues but it will not open. I open qt community an it opens a plugin loader and closes. Watching it from task manager it has multiple cmd sub processes open, a clangbackend.exe then a windows problem reporting processes starts and everything closes. I've tried rebooting and reinstalling. I'm on windows.

Comment: do you have any antivirus software running in your system?

Comment: The title should say `Qt creator` crashes not ``Qt`.

Comment: Consider installing a [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on your computer, such as [Debian](https://debian.org/). Qt5 is working very well on it (with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) C++ compiler). If using GCC, compile with all warnings and debug info, so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: I have malawarebytes and webroot both running on my computer. Running with them off changes nothing but when I installed it they were on.

Answer (score 0):

[Original Thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/76015/qt-creator-crashes-after-startup)

Try running this command in cmd.exe (command prompt):

```
c:\pathto\qtcreator -noload Welcome -noload QmlDesigner -noload QmlProfiler
```

ps: replace pathto with the path to the qt creator bin. ex = if your path to qt creator bin is, C://Program Files/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin, so the command looks like,

```
c:\Program Files\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\qtcreator -noload Welcome -noload QmlDesigner -noload QmlProfiler
```

If this opens Qt Creator, go to help menu->About Plugins and disable "Welcome" permanantly.

If the solution above doesn't work try disabling your antivirus software like McAffee.

Comment: That opens the plugin loader which, once again just crashes

Comment: Did you try disabling antivirus?

Comment: I have malawarebytes and webroot both running on my computer. Running with them off changes nothing but when I installed it they were on.

Comment: can you show a link to a screenshot of your plugin loader. it might be a plugin conflict.

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed the right qt creator for your computer's architecture? (32 bit and 64bit)